# How to render react component inside function in another component?

Tags: reactjs, function, rendering

So i need to render "Alert" component, which informs user about succesfully action in component - inside function, which adding item to cart/localstorage.

Alarm Component:

```
class Alarm extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
                <Alert color="success">
                This is a success alert — check it out!
                </Alert>
        )
    }
}
```

Function in another component:

```
addToCart = () => {
  (Some Logic...)
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I have 2 components:

- Alarm (return Alert Component)
- Product Item (include function addToCart)

After initializing function addToCard I need to render Alarm Component

---

**SOLUTION**

I declare "x" in constructor state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        quantity: 1,
        x: false
    }
}
```

And add to ProductItem component:

```
<div>
    { this.state.x &&
      <Alarm />
    }      
  </div>
```

And inside function just:

```
this.setState({x: true})
```

Comment: I can't understand what you want, please create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this is unclear.

Comment: what errors are you encountering, it looks like you are returning a component from within a render function, which is expected. what is the issue?

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean, but I think you want to show an alert when a user successfully added an item to the cart? If so, you could use the local state of the component you are developing, which could contain a value that makes the render method know whether to render the alert or not. More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Comment: @Vencovsky,

Sorry for unclear question, I edited it.

Comment: if not using global state, then if then it depends on the hierarchy of the components. it's hard to give an answer without knowing that - but i have used callbacks from child => parent to send data up (if that is the hierarchy) if alarm component is a child of the product item then it can work, it can also work if they are siblings both wrapped in a parent container. you would use the callback to set state in the parent, and the alarm component would be wrapped in a conditional within render which would display that component (or not) depending on state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you want to render Alarm(which contains Alert) component.
There are two places where you can do it.

1. **Inside Product Item component or inside any component:**
   For this one, you can use some local state or maybe a redux state

```
        render(){
          // const {showAlert} = this.props; // if redux state
          const {showAlert} = this.state; // local state
          return(
              <div>
                { showAlert &&
                  <Alarm />
                }      
              </div>
            )
          }
```

2. **Outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component:** Then you can use the [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). Because, Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component. This is mostly useful for loaders and alert message pop-ups.

Answer (score 2):

`'Standard comunication'` between components in react is done by passing props from parent to child (even a few levels deep). Read [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Common/app wide  state can be deployed using redux, context API, apollo etc.

In this case you probably need to use [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).